# <variable>! syntax in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I'm working through some legacy code for a client and I think I understand this line but I need vb expert to double-check me.

```
QS1! = Unit1.XICFMc(1)
```

My guess is that this saying:

> "If `QS1` doesn't exist, `DIM` it and assign it the value in the first position in `Unit1.XICFMc`"

Am I right? I can't find a definition for `QS1` anywhere in the project - which is what lead me to my guess above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the lack of `Option Explicit`, a variable is implicitly created when first used.

The `!` clarifies that `QS1` is of type `Single`.

Comment: ah, so it's just dim'ing the variable there and typing it as a single. Thanks!

Comment: Well I'd say *dimensioning*, since Dim is a Basic-ism taken from Fortran's DIMENSION statement.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't a trailing ! mean that the QS1 variable should be typed as Single. This is a holdover from early versions of basic that used postfixes to declare types. v$ was a string, v% was an integer etc. IIRC, you cannot have option explicit on for this to work.